# implementing Tree shaking in webpack 2 causing error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-2, native-module

I recently refactored my app to work with webpack v2. After running webpack -p I noticed My build size actually increased by ~32kb. I assume it wasn't implementing tree shaking. Thus In my .babelrc file I changed  this code:

```
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
  ]
```

**to** ==>

```
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }],
    "react",
     "stage-0",
  ]
```

But Now I'm getting the following error:

```
> webpack -p

C:\Users\jasan\Downloads\app\webpack.config.babel.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import webpack fro
m 'webpack';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at loader (C:\Users\jasan\Downloads\app\node_modules\babel-register\lib\n
ode.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\jasan\D
ownloads\app\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\jasan\Downloads\app\node_modules\webpack\bin\c
onvert-argv.js:96:18)
```

Comment: do you have babel-register and babel-core installed?

Comment: also tree-shaking works only if you enable uglifyjs

Comment: babel-register and babel-core are installed. Uglifyjs plugin is implemented.

Comment: have you tried with this command `node -r babel-register node_modules/.bin/webpack -p`?

Comment: I just did and results in: 
C:\Users\jasan\Downloads\app\node_modules\.bin\webpack:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when webpack sees `webpack.config.babel.js`, it tries to use `.babelrc` with preset es2015 and `"modules": false`, that means that it leaves `import/export` statements as it is. But node.js can't understand such syntax so you have to provide CommonJS modules for node.

One of the possible solutions is to move configuration from `.babelrc` to webpack-loader directly with `query` param

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, 
      exclude: /node_modules/, 
      loader: "babel-loader", 
      query: {
        "presets": [
          "react",
          ["es2015", { "modules": false }],
          "stage-0"
         ]
      }    
    }
  ]
}
```

and in `.babelrc` leave just plugin for converting imports to CommonJS:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

Don't forget to add necessary plugin to `package.json`

```
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.22.0"
```

For details please, check this issue as well https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1403

Comment: well , that change brought a new error:  
```ERROR in ./app/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/jasan/Downloads/app/app/index.js:
Unexpected token (28:18)

  26 |
  27 | const manifest = {
> 28 |   1: (state) => ({...state, staleReducer: undefined}),
     |                             ^
  29 |   2: (state) => ({...state, app: {...state.app, staleKey: undefined}})```

Comment: @jasan do you have `jsx` in `test` string for babel-loader?

Comment: @jasan it should just work, because spread operator is supported from stage-3 https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/

Comment: no I actually just have js in test I just tried (js|jsx) but same error

Comment: could you please share an example of code that produces error?

Comment: likely you need to play with presets ordering, it can be   ` ["es2015", { "modules": false }], "react",
          "stage-0"
         ]`

Comment: I am not sure what is causing the exact error, would a webpack config be sufficient?

Comment: here is my webpack config gist:https://gist.github.com/jasan-s/6f3eb3c86c9b76beff823bbcc3046db8

Comment: well, I'm not sure what could the problem here, maybe the issue in LoaderOptionsPlugin. Did you try to change key from `babel-loader` to babel?

Comment: anyway it looks like it's another issue. it's better to ask new question with exact problem

Answer (score 0):

in webpack.config.js

use `const webpack = require('webpack');`

instead of 
`import webpack from 'webpack';`